# Finding All Projects in TFS Referencing a Specific Assembly

Tags: .net, tfs

Is it possible getting a list of references for all projects in all solutions contained in a Team Foundation Server (TFS)?

I've been trying to access this data via the TFS SDK, but it appears it doesn't go deeper than getting a list of team projects.

The intention is to build a service that could tell you in which projects a specific assembly was being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the aspect of TFS you're looking at is code-agnostic. It serves as a source control repository for any language, not even .net, and so the concept of solutions and projects (I assume you meant .*proj) doesn't naturally fit into the TFS SDK.

You will have to create a utility that scans the team projects for .*proj files, then extract the references or other imported projects, and combines them in memory, probably in a hash-like structure. There are open source utilities that do either so you may just need to find and make them work with each other.